# Заменить слово целиком в тексте если оно содержит определенную часть

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки, replace

Например есть строка: 'Сделал работу сегодня чтобы завтра не работать'
нужно сделать replace так чтобы слова начинающиеся на 'работ' заменились полностью а не только часть.

```
const v = 'работ'
'Сделал работу сегодня чтобы завтра не работать'.replace(new RegExp(`${v}(\s?)`, 'gi'), `<b>${v}</b>`)
```

получается:

"Сделал **работ**у сегодня чтобы завтра не **работ**ать"

должно:

"Сделал **работу** сегодня чтобы завтра не **работать**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let v = 'работ';
'Сделал работу сегодня чтобы завтра не работать'.replace(
    new RegExp(`${v}\\S*`, 'gi'),
    '<b>$&</b>');
```

Ещё как вариант, можете разбивать текст на слова, а после этого для каждого слова проверять, на что оно начинается.